# Check integer column value

Tags: mysql

---

I have an integer column in MySQL table which is table empty right now. I want to check that integer column value as follow but doesn't return anything.

```
SELECT IF(PROMO_NO = '', DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y%u'), PROMO_NO) AS PROMO 
FROM PROMO_TYPE_P

// or
SELECT IF(PROMO_NO = 0, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y%u'), PROMO_NO) AS PROMO 
FROM PROMO_TYPE_P

// pehh, I tried this as well which is count value 0 but no success
SELECT IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROMO_TYPE_P) = 0, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y%u'), PROMO_NO)
AS PROMO FROM PROMO_TYPE_P
```

I don't understand the problem. Does anybody have any idea?

```
CREATE TABLE `PROMO_TYPE_P` (
  `PROMO_ID` int(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PROMO_TYPE_CODE` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `PROMO_NO` int(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `PROMO_DESC` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `PROMO_TRIGGER` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `PROMO_TYPE` int(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `PROMO_DISCOUNT` int(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `PROMO_WORK` int(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `PROMO_START_DATE` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `PROMO_END_DATE` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `PROMO_START_TIME` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `PROMO_END_TIME` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `PROMO_WORK_DAYS` int(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `PROMO_BUNDLE` int(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PROMO_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_PROMO_NO` (`PROMO_NO`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

PS: The queries that I tried must worked but nothing happened. As you can see `unique` index available in the column so I am not sure the problem related with this. I am using Toad for MySQL free edition.

[image]

**RESOLVE :**

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) = 0, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y%u'), 'DENEME') AS PROMO FROM PROMO_TYPE_P
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PROMO_NO` is defined as a not-null unsigned integer:

```
PROMO_NO int(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

In addition, it is declared as `unique`, so any value would occur on at most one row.

The query in question is:

```
SELECT IF(PROMO_NO = '', DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y%u'), PROMO_NO) AS PROMO 
FROM PROMO_TYPE_P;
```

It is doing no filtering.  So, if it is returning no rows, then it is querying an empty table.  Are you sure you are connected to the correct database?  Try running:

```
SELECT *
FROM PROMO_TYPE_P;
```

I should add that the `if` statement is mixing strings and integers.  I don't think this would result in no rows being returned, unless an error occurs (and you don't mention such an error).

EDIT:

If you want to return the current date if the table is empty and the promo otherwise, then use `union all`:

```
select max(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y%u'))
from dual
where not exists (select 1 from promo_type_p)
union all
select promo_no
from promot_type_p;
```

Comment: Dear Gordon, I understood your concerns but if you check my modified question, I tried `COUNT` function as well. The count result is `0` so the query should work with this but nothing happen.

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir . . . The table *is* empty.  What do you want to do?

Comment: Dear Gordon, if the table or column value is null, I want to generate a value based on the date.

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir . . . The column value can never be `NULL` because of the table definition, so there is no need to check for that.

Comment: Dear Gordon, I also resolved anothe way ( I had a mistake in count query )

Answer (score 1):

you are cheking for empty string while your column is integer.

try this

```
SELECT IF(PROMO_NO IS NULL, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y%u'), PROMO_NO) AS PROMO 
 FROM PROMO_TYPE_P
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT IF(PROMO_NO = '' or PROMO_NO IS NULL or PROMO_NO =0, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y%u'), PROMO_NO) AS PROMO 
FROM PROMO_TYPE_P
```

edit2.

```
 SELECT IF(PROMO_NO IS NULL, 'THERE IS NULL VALUE', 'there is no null value') AS PROMO 
 FROM PROMO_TYPE_P
```

Comment: sorry but same result, nothing happen!

Comment: how you are saying that PROMO_NO is empty right now and in your table you have this ``PROMO_NO` int(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL` with NOT NULL .?

Comment: have you default value 0 ?

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain right. I mean, I just created the table and there is no record.

Comment: the query looks nice , can you show how you are executing it , i mean your code ?

Comment: why you suing `<>` ? i have writed `IS NULL` . aand also i said the code that you executing this query ?

Comment: dear echo, as I said, I tried many way which is included your query! I have no write any code yet, just trying in Toad.

Comment: Dear echo, sorry but no work. I think there is a bug which I used `COUNT` in the query. As you might guess, count value is `0` but no success as well.

Comment: try do `select * from PROMO_TYPE_P` and see what value return the `PROMO_NO`

Comment: dear echo, nothing return just showing the column names because table empty right now.

Comment: hahhaah the table is empty what result you want get :) ? there is no record in your table even other columns :) .EMPTYYYYY

Comment: yes, the table is empty but if the table is empty I want to generate a value based on the date!

Comment: try insert some data in other columns and then use your query , but it will echo error because that column must not be NULL .